# How to boot back into Android from Ubuntu Touch?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, nexus-7, ubuntu-for-android

I just recently installed Ubuntu Touch on my Nexus 7 2013 tablet following the instructions from:

http://developer.ubuntu.com/start/ubuntu-for-devices/installing-ubuntu-for-devices/

I was successfully able to boot into Ubuntu, but now I am unsure how to boot back into android. I have tried restarting the tablet, but I am not given any option to select a different OS. I also do not have the Dual Boot back to Android application either.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

If you followed the instructions on that page you overwrote Android with Ubuntu, so there is nothing to dual boot to.  If you want to restore the backup of Android you made, there is a set of instructions linked from that page:

http://developer.ubuntu.com/start/ubuntu-for-devices/reinstalling-android/

If you want to set up your device for dual boot, you should follow the instructions on this page:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/DualBootInstallation